# Count Under OUTER JOIN Sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
SELECT 
    Ticket_No,
    _id,
    Date_Add,
    trip_no,
    f.Location_Name AS FromName,
    From_LocationID,
    To_LocationID,
    t.Location_Name AS ToName
FROM Tbl_InOut
LEFT JOIN Tbl_Ticket
    ON Tbl_InOut._id = Tbl_Ticket.Trip_ID
LEFT JOIN Tbl_Location AS f
    ON f.Location_ID = Tbl_Ticket.From_LocationID
LEFT JOIN Tbl_Location AS t
    ON t.Location_ID = Tbl_Ticket.To_LocationID

UNION ALL

SELECT Ticket_No,
    _id,
    Date_Add,
    trip_no,
    f.Location_Name AS FromName,
    From_LocationID,
    To_LocationID,
    t.Location_Name AS ToName
FROM Tbl_Ticket
LEFT JOIN Tbl_InOut
    ON Tbl_InOut._id = Tbl_Ticket.Trip_ID
LEFT JOIN Tbl_Location AS f
    ON f.Location_ID = Tbl_Ticket.From_LocationID
LEFT JOIN Tbl_Location AS t
    ON t.Location_ID = Tbl_Ticket.To_LocationID
```

[image]

First at all Tbl_InOut Left Join The Tbl_Ticket and
Tbl_Location LEFT JOIN with Tbl_Ticket this is the result, right now i would like to count how many data are from From_LocationID to To_Location

Example Ticket_No 1,2,3,4,5 is from_LocationID 1 to To_LocationID 3 total is 5 so beside the To_Name Column will add one more column name TotalCount and the this 5 rows under TotalCount Column value is 5 , the less i wont explain please see the above picture i have added totalCount column with the value i want

### EDIT

1 Counter is work fine but, 2 count data will become double, how to solve, this is my  SQL

```
SELECT
       Ticket_No,_id,Date_Add, trip_no,f.Location_Name as FromName,From_LocationID,To_LocationID,t.Location_Name as ToName,PriceType_ID,Amount,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tbl_Ticket WHERE Trip_ID = Tbl_InOut._id AND Tbl_Ticket.From_LocationID = f.Location_ID AND t.Location_ID = Tbl_Ticket.To_LocationID AND Tbl_Ticket.PriceType_ID = 0) AS NormalCount,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tbl_Ticket WHERE Trip_ID = Tbl_InOut._id AND Tbl_Ticket.From_LocationID = f.Location_ID AND t.Location_ID = Tbl_Ticket.To_LocationID AND Tbl_Ticket.PriceType_ID > 0) AS DiscountCount

FROM   Tbl_InOut
        LEFT JOIN Tbl_Ticket ON Tbl_InOut._id = Tbl_Ticket.Trip_ID
        LEFT JOIN Tbl_Location as f On f.Location_ID = Tbl_Ticket.From_LocationID
        LEFT JOIN Tbl_Location as t On t.Location_ID = Tbl_Ticket.To_LocationID
UNION ALL
SELECT
       Ticket_No,_id,Date_Add, trip_no,f.Location_Name as FromName,From_LocationID,To_LocationID,t.Location_Name as ToName ,PriceType_ID,Amount,
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tbl_Ticket WHERE Trip_ID = Tbl_InOut._id AND Tbl_Ticket.From_LocationID = f.Location_ID AND t.Location_ID = Tbl_Ticket.To_LocationID AND Tbl_Ticket.PriceType_ID = 0) AS NormalCount,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tbl_Ticket WHERE Trip_ID = Tbl_InOut._id AND Tbl_Ticket.From_LocationID = f.Location_ID AND t.Location_ID = Tbl_Ticket.To_LocationID AND Tbl_Ticket.PriceType_ID > 0) AS DiscountCount
FROM   Tbl_Ticket
        LEFT JOIN Tbl_InOut  ON Tbl_InOut._id = Tbl_Ticket.Trip_ID
        LEFT JOIN Tbl_Location as f On f.Location_ID = Tbl_Ticket.From_LocationID
        LEFT JOIN Tbl_Location as t On t.Location_ID = Tbl_Ticket.To_LocationID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a correlated subquery to count how many records match:

```
SELECT
    ...,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM Tbl_Ticket
     WHERE Trip_ID = Tbl_InOut._id
    ) AS TotalCount
FROM ...
```

Comment: It is unclear what "data becomes double" means. Put an example on [SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5), and don't reuse the same question for two different questions.